# Error displaying an event between two months

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm having problems with the `nextDayThreshold` option. Even when I´m setting it to "08:00:00", `FullCalendar` is duplicating events that finish at "07:00:00" on the 1st of a month, displaying it with a left arrow in `timelineMonth`, showing the same event in two months:

[image: Same event in two months]

```
$(function() { // document ready

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
    nextDayThreshold: '08:00:00',
    header: {
      left: 'today prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'timelineMonth'
    },
    defaultView: 'timelineMonth',
    resourceColumns: [
        {
            labelText: 'first column',
            field: 'title',
            width: 150
        }
    ],
    resources: [{
      id: 'a',
      title: 'Auditorium A',
    }, {
      id: 'b',
      title: 'Auditorium B',
      eventColor: 'green'
    }, {
      id: 'c',
      title: 'Auditorium C',
      eventColor: 'orange'
    }],
    events: [{
      id: '1',
      resourceId: 'b',
      start: '2018-10-31T21:00:00',
      end: '2018-11-01T07:00:00',
      title: 'event 1'
    }]
  });

});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/makelele24/q2fk57nb/4/)

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No, it's not a bug.

Long answer:
The [documentation for nextDayThreshold](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/nextDayThreshold) says:

> Only affects timed events that appear on whole-days. Whole-day cells
>   occur in month view, basicDay, basicWeek and the all-day slots in the
>   agenda views.

In a "timeline" view, even though the slotDuration is set to 1 day by default in a "timelineMonth" view, fullCalendar still regards these as *timed* slots, rather than *whole-day* cells. Therefore the nextDayThreshold rules do not apply. e.g. If you changed to a timelineWeek view, it still uses exactly the same layout and slots, except the slots have a different length. They're not a different kind of cell.

If we look at an updated version of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q2fk57nb/6/ which now includes a regular "month" view (I simply added `right: 'timelineMonth,month'` to the header) we can see that the same event in that view is confined to the 31st October, because of the nextDayThreshold rule, and the fact that the regular "month" view uses "whole-day" cells.

Comment: Thank you so much! I already fixed this "wrong" behaviour in `EventRender` but I wondered why that was happening.

Comment: I was thinking about you said of `nextDayThreshold` rules don´t apply in `timelineMonth` view and I´m not sure about that because that value affects the way my events are represented except of the case of my question. Perhaps your explanation solves my question but it surely apply.

Comment: @JorgeAntequera "that value affects the way my events are represented"...that's interesting, but I don't know how to reproduce it...can you update your JSFiddle to show an actual example of this occuring, please?

Comment: I mean, `nextDayThreshold` is not ignored by events and keeps working establishing a line between events that belong to one day or/and the next but not in that particular case.https://jsfiddle.net/makelele24/q2fk57nb/10/

Comment: Ok I see, your sample data makes it clearer now. You're right, that is odd. It does appear like it might be a bug of some sort, possibly relating to the fact that the event happens to fall across the boundary of the view's date range. Also, fullCalendar is cleverer than I thought (and also contradicts the documentation somewhat) in making 1-day slots in a timeline behave like whole-day cells - mostly! P.S. Your Fiddle was using a different version of the Scheduler CSS than the JS (1.5 vs 1.9), so I updated it to make sure that wasn't the issue. It's not: https://jsfiddle.net/q2fk57nb/11/

Comment: Anyway if you're satisfied it's a bug, here's the procedure for raising one - https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs. I'm happy to delete this answer if it proves to be incorrect / misleading.